# Special Language Characters not displaying

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to add languages with special characters in CkEditor but It doesn't seem to work. I've tried adding `config.language = 'sv';` to the config.js which didnt work so I installed language addon, also didnt help...

When I type in a text and submit it, It doesnt display rest of the text from where the special character was added.

`Det här är en test` (This is a test)
Which later on is displayed as `Det h`

UPDATE:

AJAX CALL

```
$('.newcomment_submit').click(function(){
      var newcomment_txtarea = CKEDITOR.instances['comment_txtarea'].getData();
      $.ajax({
        url:'/tsw/pages/s_comment.php',
        type:'post',
        data:$('.comment_form').serialize()+'&newcomment_txtarea='+newcomment_txtarea,
        success: function(data){
          alert(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```
  session_start();
  require('connect.php');
  if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    echo "err#sess";
  } else {
    if(strlen($_POST['newcomment_txtarea']) < 5) {
      echo "err#shortcmt";
    } else {
      if($dbh->exec('INSERT INTO `comments`(`post_id`,`commenter_id`,`comment`) VALUES('.$dbh->quote($_POST['post_id']).','.$dbh->quote($_POST['commenter_id']).','.$dbh->quote($_POST['newcomment_txtarea']).')')){
        echo "success";
      } else {
        echo "err#insert";
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What does the `submit` do? Send it to the server? Save the value in the database? Do you know what/where exactly is your problem?

Comment: I send the text to a php script with the help of ajax call. Its saved in Database

Comment: Ok, so does it look correct in database?

Comment: So maybe the problem is in your database? Do you know **exactly** where is the problem?

Comment: It doesn't even send it to the ajax.

Comment: Add the code that is relevant for sending the data

Comment: @Dekel added it now

Comment: @IdontReallywolf do you get any errors in console? Is the url your ajax call uses accurate and properly points to the php script?

Comment: no errors, yes url parameters are correct. If they weren't english texts wouldn't be uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research on the problem I have found a solution which is basically adding
**`config.entities = false;`** to the **`config.js`** file and special language characters won't be escaped.